# Weird mail issue

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server

I've got this little script:

```
$to      = 'atsome@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: Admin <admin@mysite.com>' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: admin@mysite.com' . "\r\n" ;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-fadmin@mysite.com");
```

And it works fine when I am sending to a gmail/yahoo/outlook/w.e address with this log:

```
Jun  2 18:18:27 beast postfix/pickup[5947]: 2E93F4060261: uid=1060 from=<admin@mysite.com>
Jun  2 18:18:27 beast postfix/cleanup[8944]: 2E93F4060261: message-id=<20160602151827.random@myhostname>
Jun  2 18:18:27 beast postfix/qmgr[46425]: 2E93F4060261: from=<admin@mysite.com>, size=364, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  2 18:18:27 beast postfix/smtp[10480]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c01::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Jun  2 18:18:27 beast postfix/smtp[10480]: 2E93F4060261: to=<atsome@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.136.27]:25, delay=0.3, delays=0.01/0/0.06/0.23, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1464880687 uk6si1260730wjc.239 - gsmtp)
Jun  2 18:18:27 beast postfix/qmgr[46425]: 2E93F4060261: removed
```

But if I try to send an email to my own site (for example instead of `atsome@gmail.com` I use `test@mysite.com` I receive no email and I get the following log:

```
Jun  2 18:19:54 beast postfix/pickup[5947]: C208C4060261: uid=1060 from=<admin@mysite.com>
Jun  2 18:19:54 beast postfix/cleanup[8944]: C208C4060261: message-id=<20160602151954.random@myhostname>
Jun  2 18:19:54 beast postfix/qmgr[46425]: C208C4060261: from=<admin@mysite.com>, size=366, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  2 18:19:56 beast postfix/local[10994]: C208C4060261: to=<test.mysite@myhostname>, orig_to=<test@mysite.com>, relay=local, delay=2.1, delays=0.02/0/0/2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME)
Jun  2 18:19:56 beast postfix/qmgr[46425]: C208C4060261: removed
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Depends on your `mysite.com` mail server setting.  You don't want to relay mail for other domain, and also, some setting will mail server origin, disallow direct client connection without authentication.

Answer (score 2):

What's the hostname of the server where this script is on, and what's the hostname of your mail server (if different)? If they fall under the same domain but they are in fact 2 different servers, then it's likely Postfix "thinks" email sent to the domain name should be delivered locally - and so ignores MX records and does just that.

This would explain why emails don't actually leave the box.

(Your logs do indicate that the email is being delivered locally).

Comment: They've got the same hostname and it is a single server. The problem is no email is being delivered though :/

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like your own email flows through that same server. This is an interesting item in your log: "delivered to command: /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME" ... Am I correct in thinking that you're using Webmin / Virtualmin?